# Examples of recursion with caching

Tags: caching, recursion, pseudocode

I'm trying to learn more about recursion. So far I have discovered **tail-recursion** and now I discovered **caching inside recursive functions/methods**. However, I cannot find any good examples (other than fibonacci) that present recursion with caching. For the moment I don't really care about the caching technique, whether it's naive or advanced caching.

So, I'm requesting examples from the community.

To avoid confusion, please provide pseudocode, not code in a specific language.

* I learn a lot by examples and by reading other people's code, that's why I ask for them.

Comment: Are you thinking of memoisation?

Comment: Not only, memorization is not exactly caching. However, it achieves similar results. I have already read a few topics focusing on memoization. So I want to focus only on caching.

Comment: How is what you're describing *not* memoization?